# tsp fails to run the bash command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use ts/tsp to schedule idle tasks that I need done from time to time, which is OK if they don't complete due to a crash.

So far, I'm trying with a script like this:

```
the_args=(--long-arg /usr/share/lib  --long-arg2 -j $j -o "'$path_o/'" -i "'$path_i'")

tsp -m -L "$jobname"  bash -c '
    echo task "$@"
    cgexec -g cpu,freezer:execting exector "$@"
' "${the_args[@]}"
```

I want to run executor with the args given by `the_args`

I've tried many alternatives, including:

```
tsp -m -L "$jobname"  bash -c "
    echo task ${the_args[@]}
    cgexec -g cpu,freezer:execting exector ${the_args[@]}
"
```

I've also tried with heredocs with different configurations.... None of them worked.

Unfortunately, none of those allow me to call the command with all the args. Some methods pass only the first element in the list (the ones shown), others don't even work.

What is the correct way to pass parameters to inside the deferred script?

Comment: @Inian I don't understand correctly what you mean...., so I'll try this: `the_args` need to be accessed inside the dynamic bash script. The command that really needs them is `exector`
The arguments can be written directly to the string that is `eval`ed by bash.
Does that help?

Comment: Ok. In that case, what error are you seeing for the second approach `bash -c "echo task ${the_args[@]}
cgexec -g cpu,freezer:execting exector ${the_args[@]}
"`

Comment: @Inian Only the first element from the list is sent to the command and `exector` complains the other ones are not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument following `-c`'s argument is used to set `$0` in the shell; it is *not* included in `$@`. You need to provide some dummy argument (since you probably don't care what `$0` actually is).

Your quoting inside `the_args` also needs to be simpilfied.

```
the_args=(
  --long-arg /usr/share/lib
  --long-arg2
  -j "$j"
  -o "$path_o/"
  -i "$path_i"
)

tsp -m -L "$jobname"  bash -c '
  echo task "$@"
  cgexec -g cpu,freezer:execting exector "$@"
  ' "" "${the_args[@]}"
```

Comment: I was so close to this and I gave up. This does solve it. Thank you!